# Can't get nodemon to ignore my public folder

Tags: node.js, nodemon

I've been trying to get nodemon to ignore my public folder for a while now, and not having much luck...

I've created nodemon.json in my root directory next to my package.json. In this I just have the following commands...

```
{
  "name": "nodemon",
  "homepage": "http://nodemon.io",
  "nodemonConfig": {
    "ignore": ["public/*"],
    "delay": "2500"
  }
}
```

I've tried many iterations of the way the directory is written above, but having no luck - as soon as a file is altered in the public folder the server resets.

Also, the public folder is one level up from the root, definitely in the right location.

Any ideas?! I don't particularly want to use flags each time I run nodemon if I can avoid it as thats a faff... Potentially its not reading my nodemon.json file...?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

this worked for me, get rid of the " * " 
in the **"ignore": ["public/*"]**,

This code is written in the ***nodemon.json*** config folder, so create it and write this code in it, nodemon will see that folder and read the config, more about this on [nodemon npm page](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon)

```
{
  "verbose": true,
  "ignore": ["public/", "README"]
}
```